# ANTLR3 parser fails when using memoize

Tags: java, parsing, antlr3, java-6

## Context

I'm making some changes to a grammar parser in ANTLR3 to recognize certain URLs that I consider *valid* (for example, if it begins with `www` or `http`, or if it ends with `.com`)

The main rule I have right now is something like this:

```
url returns [UrlToken token]
  : scheme_full? subdomain? middle_url valid_domain_end? port? path_full? 
    {isValidUrl($scheme_full.text, $subdomain.text, $valid_domain_end.text, $path_full.text, $middle_url.text)}?
    {$token = urlTokenFor(
      StringUtils.defaultString($scheme_full.text), 
      StringUtils.defaultString($subdomain.text) + StringUtils.defaultString($middle_url.text) + StringUtils.defaultString($valid_domain_end.text), 
      StringUtils.defaultString($path_full.text), 
      StringUtils.defaultString($port.text), 
      StringUtils.defaultString(null) ); }
  ;
```

And the code of `isValidUrl` is:

```
private boolean isValidUrl(String scheme, String subdomain, String valid_end, String path, String middle) {
    if (scheme != null || subdomain != null || valid_end != null) return true;
    if (path != null && middle.contains(".")) return true;
    return false;
}
```

The main idea is that I let the sub-parts match optionally, then check if it's a *valid* URL using some Java function, and then (in case it is valid) it returns a `UrlToken`.

I did it like this because the logic to check if a URL is valid was too complicated to leave it to the parser, generated a lot of ambiguity which I wasn't able to fix.

Now, this is **currently working fine for me**, and is matching the URLs that I want.

The problem is that before the changes I was using the `memoize` option, and I had to deactivate it to make it work. Since performance is important I'd like to be able to keep memoization enabled.

## Why is it failing when using memoize?

I did some debugging on the generated Java code.

This is a piece of the generated code for the `url` rule:

```
// grammars/Url.g:94:5: ( scheme_full )?
int alt3=2;
int LA3_0 = input.LA(1);
if ( (LA3_0==LETTERS) ) {
    int LA3_1 = input.LA(2);
    if ( (LA3_1==SYMBOL) ) {
        int LA3_3 = input.LA(3);
        if ( (LA3_3==SYMBOL) ) {
            int LA3_4 = input.LA(4);
            // Inside synpred3_Url(), scheme_full() is executed 
            if ( ((synpred3_Url()&&(matchesScheme(input.LT(1))))) ) {
                alt3=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
switch (alt3) {
    case 1 :
        // grammars/Url.g:0:0: scheme_full
        {
        pushFollow(FOLLOW_scheme_full_in_url100);
        scheme_full2=scheme_full();
        state._fsp--;
        if (state.failed) return retval;
        }
        break;
}
```

And this is the generated code for the `scheme_full` as an example:

```
public final Url.scheme_full_return scheme_full() throws RecognitionException {
    Url.scheme_full_return retval = new Url.scheme_full_return();
    retval.start = input.LT(1);
    int scheme_full_StartIndex = input.index();
    try {
        if ( state.backtracking>0 && alreadyParsedRule(input, 13) ) { return retval; }
        // grammars/Url.g:149:3: ( scheme scheme_separator )
        // grammars/Url.g:149:5: scheme scheme_separator
        {
        pushFollow(FOLLOW_scheme_in_scheme_full374);
        scheme();
        state._fsp--;
        if (state.failed) return retval;
        pushFollow(FOLLOW_scheme_separator_in_scheme_full376);
        scheme_separator();
        state._fsp--;
        if (state.failed) return retval;
        }
        retval.stop = input.LT(-1);
    }
    catch (RecognitionException re) {
        reportError(re);
        recover(input,re);
    }
    finally {
        if ( state.backtracking>0 ) { memoize(input, 13, scheme_full_StartIndex); }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

This are the conclusions I've come to so far:

- Each rule becomes a Java function, each one is **executed twice**,

  - the first one in the form of a backtracking to "predict" if the term will be used,
  - and the second one when it's actually matching.
- The return values of the terms such as `scheme_full`, `subdomain`, etc. are of the type `ParserRuleReturnScope`, which contains start and stop tokens.
- When `memoize` is set to `true`, the first time the terms are executed if the result is successful, it is cached, so that the second time it's gonna execute it doesn't need to do all over again. When the first time is successful (before putting the result in cache) the result (`retval`) has both start and end tokens properly set.
- The problem is that the second time it is executed, and uses the cached result, the stop token comes in `null` (although the first execution was successful). It can be seen in the `scheme_full` code, when `retval` is returned it doesn't have the stop token set yet.
- This last thing becomes a problem because when executing the predicate (the `isValidUrl`) it uses the text attribute of the term, using `$scheme_full.text` for example. And because the end token is in `null`, calling the text attribute to the scope returns a `null` string, and so my validation fails, **even though** the match was successful.
- This whole behavior doesn't happen when `memoize` is set to `false`.

Any idea how can I solve this?